# setVisibility not working on all items in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

so I have recycler view show 4 items, I have code that unlocks the card and remove lock view so the problem is code work in the first 2 visible items but when I scroll to item 3 it has same code in it but set visibility GONE don't work even when I see it call-in log

here is code java:

```
  if (datassss[position] == "Beginner") {
                holder.hpim1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[position] == biglimits[cat]) {
                    holder.hpim1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win5));
                }
            }
            if (datassss[position] == "Elementary") {
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] != biglimits[cat]) {
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] == biglimits[cat]) {
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                holder.hpim1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.hpim2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.Main_lessons_num_text.setText("4lessons");
                holder.main_big_imagex.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.h_sb_ele_tree));
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[position] == elelimits[cat]) {
                    holder.hpim1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win5));
                    holder.hpim2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win2));
                }
            }
            if (datassss[position] == "Intermediate") {
                Log.e("found limit", learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] + " fl");
                Log.e("limit", elelimits[cat] + " l");

                if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] != elelimits[cat]) {
                    Log.e("limit",  "unlock");
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] == elelimits[cat]) {
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.hpim1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.hpim2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.hpim3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.Main_lessons_num_text.setText("5lessons");
                holder.main_big_imagex.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tree2));
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[position] == interlimits[cat]) {
                    holder.hpim1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win5));
                    holder.hpim2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win2));
                    holder.hpim3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win6));
                }
            }
```

here is my log i debug witch show say to visibility call :

> 2020-10-16 09:28:04.441 21853-21853/ E/limit: unlock
> 2020-10-16 09:28:04.441 21853-21853/ E/found limit: 4 fl
> 2020-10-16 09:28:04.441 21853-21853/ E/limit: 4 l

but as you can you in the image of the emulator view is not gone[image]

[image]

all have the same code but it only works with visible items at first
plz help me what's wrong
thanks

Comment: You have handle both cases if and else part because `Viewholder` is being reused .

Comment: @ADM they all call at the same time it works in first 2 items but when I scroll same code won't work on 3 or 4 items of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the beginning and before all if statements

```
holder.hpim1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.hpim2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.hpim3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Update**

Try to replace `elelimits` with `biglimits`  in "Intermediate" if statement. Like that:

```
            if (datassss[position] == "Intermediate") {
                Log.e("found limit", learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] + " fl");
                Log.e("limit", elelimits[cat] + " l");

                if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] != biglimits[cat]) {
                    Log.e("limit",  "unlock");
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] == biglimits[cat]) {
                    holder.miimlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.hpim1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.hpim2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.hpim3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.Main_lessons_num_text.setText("5lessons");
                holder.main_big_imagex.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tree2));
                if (learnprogresdatacat1[position] == interlimits[cat]) {
                    holder.hpim1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win5));
                    holder.hpim2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win2));
                    holder.hpim3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_win6));
                }
            }
```

Comment: they noting about lock they work fine my problem with holder.miimlock witch is a black view for the lock as you see in image in xml view it default is gone

Comment: try to replace `elelimits` with `biglimits ` in "Intermediate" if statement

Comment: elelimits is int array that shows how much lessons in each category so i cant set biggner but i also try it it doesnt work if you see me log in qus it say if con call but setvisiable dont work

Comment: What logcal shows `Log.e("found limit", learnprogresdatacat1[getexacposition] + " fl");`

Comment: limit: unlock 2020-10-16 09:28:04.441 21853-21853/ E/found limit: 4 fl 2020-10-16 09:28:04.441 21853-21853/ E/limit: 4 l this my log both numbers is 4 so its correct and it say its unlock in the log but in the emulator as you can see its still lock

Comment: Try to hide `holder.hpim3` and  not set image for `holder.main_big_imagex`

Comment: holder.hpim3 or 1 2 3 is that smile faces you can see in image used in question they work fine. black lock view which it calls holder.miimlock  setvisable won't work when i scroll to the right items show after I scroll lock don't gone but same code work on Beginner and elementary but not Intermediate or advance i send new image from list and cate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223135/discussion-between-er-reflex-and-yeldar-n).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not handling the visibility in all else part of your if's. You you are setting a component to be visible in a if statement, make sure to make it invisible in the else statement.Otherwise this issue will persist.
The root cause of this issue is the view gets recycled and the old visibility is retained if you are not handling the visibility correctly.

Comment: i try else con it same still lock view show i mean if{}else{}